# Servicestack cross site Auth conundrum

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-auth

I have an MVC website (single page JS app type thing) which can have the SS NuGets installed if needed.

I have an API which is currently (and very successfully) using the SS auth plugins to allow me to authenticate users via twitter, fb etc. This API is currently allowing a PHP frontend to gain access.

I want the MVC site to be able to authenticate in the same way as the PHP site but I want it to happen in a more MVC/SS way - rather that just checking for an ss-id and if it's not present redirect to a login page. I'm not a PHP dev but my understanding is that when a user requests a page on the PHP site - it checks for the existence of an ss-id in the cookies - if there is one then the user has already authenticated, if not then the user is not authenticated and is pushed to /login on the PHP site which has the authenticate by twitter, fb etc buttons.

How can I do this? I can add the SS Authenticate attribute to the controller but would that be enough?

So the workflow would be;

user goes to http://somesite.com

They aren't logged in so they are redirected to http://somesite.com/login

They click the twitter login button on that page and are redirected to

http://api.somesite.com/auth/twitter where they are forwarded to twitter to authenticate

Once authenticated they are sent back to http://somesite.com with a valid sesssion

Now - my question is, can I authenticate them like this?

If so, what would be the best way of doing this? I want to just add the `[Authenticate]` attribute to the controller and be done with it. If I set up the `RavenUserAuthRepository` to look at the same place as the API for the Db and add the `[Authenticate]` attribute it doesn't seem to be enough?

[Another edit]

So - I have now added the plugins to the MVC site so that I can go to somesite.com/auth/twitter and this uses the same `RavenUserAuthRepository` that the api uses - so it shares a database.

I have created a seperate twitter app so it can redirect properly.

Everything seems to be working in terms of logging in. Except for when I try to go to the controller with `[Authenticate]` on it - `TryAuthenticate` inside the `RavenUserAuthRepository` is never called...

For the rest of the workflow - when it comes back from twitter having authenticated it is calling the methods in the `RavenUserAuthRepository` such as `GetUserAuth`

Comment: I don't understand what this means `I want the MVC site to be able to authenticate in the same way as the PHP site but I want it to happen in a more MVC/SS way - rather that just checking for an ss-id and if it's not present redirect to a login page.` Can you clarify how the PHP site works? I also think you should split the questions. :)

Comment: edited - can you remove your close request now? :)

Comment: Done :) So do you have the scenario `End User` > `MVC Site` > `ServiceStack API`? Where the End User uses the ServiceStack API through the MVC? And as such you want the `End User` to be redirected to the `MVC`'s login page that shows the options to login using twitter, fb etc when authentication fails at the ServiceStack API?

Comment: Edited main question...

Comment: Are you inheriting from ServiceStackController?

Comment: Yeah - not the generic type though as I don't have a custom session

Comment: That's fine, it should redirect if the user is not Authenticated, is that's now what's happening? If not can you override **AuthenticationErrorResult** property in your controller to see if it's getting called?

Comment: Yeah - it redirects - but it never calls into the repo to authenticate

Comment: It's not meant to, it just redirects to the /auth service if they're not already authenticated.

Comment: But it's doing that even when I am authenticated

Comment: It should only redirect when [session.IsAuthenticated = false](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Mvc/ExecuteServiceStackFiltersAttribute.cs#L17-L22). Also use a @mention (e.g. @mythz) when replying in comments so we get notified there's new comments. The author of the question/answer doesn't need it as they'll automatically get notified, but other commenters wont.

Comment: @mythz - I have added you to a github repo which I think illustrates my current position. I've added notes to the readme.md